# Why is this code throwing a null pointer exception

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I am trying to write a recursive parser combinator class

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
class MyParser extends RegexParsers {
  override val skipWhitespace = true
  val singleValue = "[\\p{L}][\\p{L}0-9_\\*]*".r
  val expr : Parser[Any] = subExpr ~ rep("&" ~ subExpr | "|" ~ subExpr)
  val subExpr : Parser[Any] = singleValue | "(" ~ expr ~ ")"
}
```

When I try to instantiate it. it throws a null pointer exception

```
val parser = new MyParser 

java.lang.NullPointerException
  ammonite.$sess.cmd8$MyParser.<init>(cmd8.sc:4)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd9$.<init>(cmd9.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd9$.<clinit>(cmd9.sc)
```

I am really at a loss to understand why. There is absolutely nothing in the code which should result in a null pointer exception at the time of construction. Not sure what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two members of `MyParser`, `expr` and `subExpr`, must be initialized every time `MyParser` is created, but they reference each other. They are evaluated in order, and when evaluating `expr` `subExpr` is still set to `null`. A simplified version of this problem is:

```
class Bad {
    val one = two - 1
    val two = one + 1
}
```

You might want to change `expr` and `subExpr` to be methods (using `def`), so they aren't retrieved until needed.

See also [FAQ: Why is my abstract or overridden val null?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html)